# How to randomly update a column if the number of records between the 2 join tables are not equal in Postgres sql

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, sql-update

Table 1(5 records):

| id | name | date | units |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abc | 3/16/2021 |  |
| 1 | abc | 3/17/2021 |  |
| 1 | abc | 3/18/2021 |  |
| 1 | abc | 3/19/2021 |  |
| 1 | abc | 3/20/2021 |  |

Table 2(3 records):

| id | name | startdate | enddate | units |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abc | 3/16/2021 | 03/23/2021 | 2 |
| 1 | abc | 3/16/2021 | 03/23/2021 | 2 |
| 1 | abc | 3/16/2021 | 03/23/2021 | 2 |

Below is the join condition:

```
select * from Table1 a right join Table2 b on
(a.id = b.id) and (a.name = b.name) and (a.date between b.startdate and b.enddate)
```

I am trying to update the units columns in Table 1 from Table 2. My requirement is since there are 3 records in Table 2, only 3 records in Table 1 should be updated based on the above join condition. It can be random. But the number of records updated should not go above 3.

I tried doing this.

```
with e as 
(select *,
row_number() over(partition by a.id
order by id) as rn
from Table1 a right join Table 2 b on (a.id = b.id) and (a.name = b.name) and (a.date between b.startdate and b.enddate)
)

update table1
set units = e.units
from e
where e.rn = 1
```

However, in this case all 5 records get updated. How do I resolve this? Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Your data has exact duplicates in the table.  That is one version.  However, this becomes really complicated if only some rows match between the two tables.

Comment: Yes @GordonLinoff, since the number of records between the two tables don't match I am having a hard time trying to write a code for this.

Comment: . . What I am saying is that exact duplicates are a *simplification*.  The general problem is much harder to solve.  I'm asking for clarity.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, Thank you again. Actually this is the exact dataset I have with columns names changed. We are doing a POC and want this joined somehow. I have not simplified anything, except the number of records will be much larger. Can you please assist me with the code of this version?

Answer (score 1):

Join the tables together.  Then choose one row from from table2 for each row in table1 and do the update:

```
update table1 t1
    set t1.units = t2.units
    from (select distinct on (t1.id, t1.name, t1.date) t1.*, t2.units
          from table1 t1 join
               table2 t2
               on t2.id = t1.id and t2.name = t1.name and
                  t1.date between t2.startdate and t2.enddate
          order by t1.id, t1.name, t1.date, random())
         ) tt1 
    where tt1.name = t1.name and
          tt1.id = t1.id and
          tt1.date = t1.date;
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. But the thing is if I use this, all 5 records in Table 1 would get updated. I need to somehow update only 3 records out of 5 in Table 1 since in table b there are 3 records. Those 3 records can be anything random out of the 5.